# How to change the shape and opacity of JInternalFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

We can change the shape and opacity of JFrame using setShape() and setOpacity() respectively. Is there any possible way to change the shape and opacity of JInternalFrame ? Thank you.

```
import java.awt.geom.Arc2D; 
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D; 
import javax.swing.JFrame; 

public class RotatingWheel extends JFrame 
{ 
     public RotatingWheel() { 
          setUndecorated(true); 
          setSize(500, 500); 
          setLocation(500, 150); 
          setVisible(true); 
          setOpacity(0.6f); 
          setShape(new Arc2D.Double(new Rectangle2D.Double(5, 25, 385, 385), 90, 360, Arc2D.PIE));     
      } 

      public static void main(String args[]) 
      { 
              new RotatingWheel();
      } 
}
```

Comment: please where, why and whats reason,

Comment: setShape() and setOpacity() is about Translucency or ???

Comment: Respected sir, i have created circular translucent jframe in separate class,this frame contains buttons. Now my problem is when i create the object of this class from my Main class,it creates separate frame so i want to make it jinternalframe but as soon as i make it jinternalframe,setOpacity() and setShape() showing error.

Comment: sir,i want to avoid that separate frame , so i want to make it jinternalframe within main window.

Comment: as soon as i make it jinternalframe,setOpacity() and setShape() showing error. for better help sooenr post an SSCCE, short, runnable, compilable, generating a.m. exception

Comment: sir, may i post my code over here ?

Comment: sure, code in SSCCE form talking thousands of words

Comment: @user3008532, Remove your above comment. Add your code to your question by editing. I have done it this time for you

Comment: Thank you Sage sir i will take care of that hereafter but i am still stuck at the same problem of jinternalframe.